# Was the The Mask 1994 (and subsequent cartoon) inspired by The Mask 1961

Tags: the-mask, the-mask-1961

Is the mask from [*The Mask* (1994)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110475/) and the TV show [*The Mask*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112064/) in any way inspired by the movie [*The Mask* (1961)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055151/)?

Comment: Are you asking whether the masks are related (in universe) or whether the movies are in some way related (out of universe) - i.e. one inspired the other?  Also do you have any suggestion that they may be so?

Comment: Out of the universe. I do have a suggestion. Both have similar ideas. Wear a mask, get the inner desires out. I also found some character resemblances here and there. Was wondering may be the animated series was inspired from the movie.

Comment: The animated series was an extension of the 1994 movie and used some of the same characters.  The 1961 movie shared none of the same characters as either the comic book or the 1994 movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The 1994 version was based off of Norse mythology, as the wearer of the mask became a reincarnation of Loki (yes, the same Loki from Thor/The Avengers fame, and a bonafide prankster) whereas the 1961 Mask was a psychological thriller/horror movie where the wearer of the mask was slowly driven insane.  There is a fine line between becoming a prankster and committing murder, but the line exists, nonetheless.

However, in a larger context, the 1994 movie was based on the Dark Horse comic of the same name, which shared a closer storyline with the 1961 movie.  The 1994 version was also intended to be a horror series, but the story was changed along the way.  So, in some cases they are, in fact, related.

Comment: Yup they might be related. Both the series and the 1961 movie kind of have similar ideas and some character resemblance here and there. I kind of had a thought that the comic was inspired from the movie.

Comment: It would seem the short answer is no, and the long answer is kinda.